# SQL query for values consisting of only a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How would I query for values that only consist of a specific character, regardless of length?

I have a table as follows:

```
CustID  MAC_Addr
001     AV4A46299992
002     99999
003     A8JEO943K8
004     999999999999
005     A99K0O37DG49
006     999
007     9
```

I'm trying to figure out a query that would return only CustID 002, 004, 006 and 007 because their MAC_Addr contains only 9's - and nothing else, regardless of length; but want to ensure I don't pull in others that have consecutive 9's (like CustID 001).

Relative newbie here, so could be something simple I'm not aware of, just not having much luck.  Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select CustID,MAC_Addr From table_name Where MOD(MAC_Addr,9)=0;

**EDIT:**

Select CustID,MAC_Addr From table_name Where REGEXP_LIKE (MAC_Addr,'^[[:digit:]]+$') and MOD(MAC_Addr,9)=0;

**EDIT:2**
Select CustID,MAC_Addr From table_name Where REGEXP_LIKE (MAC_Addr,'^[[:digit:]]+$') and MAC_Addr>0 and MOD(MAC_Addr,9)=0 ;

Comment: Thanks, Shankar. I'm getting the following when I attempt this: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number";  The datatype for this field is VARCHAR(20), would that be related to this error?

Comment: Sorry about that. When the MOD function encounters the other alphanumeric values it throws invalid number error. Here is the updated SQL.Hopefully the following SQL will work. 
 "Select CustID,MAC_Addr From table_name Where REGEXP_LIKE (MAC_Addr,'^[[:digit:]]+$') and MOD(MAC_Addr,9)=0;"

Comment: Thank you. This got me much closer, Shankar. The only issue I encountered with the above is that it included an entry that had 4 zeroes ('0000') in that field. Thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: If this is just to do it for fields having zeroes.This should do it. EDIT2: Select CustID,MAC_Addr From table_name Where REGEXP_LIKE (MAC_Addr,'^[[:digit:]]+$') and MAC_Addr>0 and MOD(MAC_Addr,9)=0 ;

Comment: Thanks again, Shankar. This appears to have solved it!

Answer (score 3):

The following should work in almost any SQL dialect:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(mac_addr, left(mac_addr, 1), '') = '';
```

EDIT:

If you only care about `'9'`, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(mac_addr, '9', '') = '';
```

EDIT II:

Okay, Oracle doesn't support `LEFT()`, so do the same thing with `SUBSTR()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(mac_addr, substr(mac_addr, 1, 1), '') = '';
```

Comment: Add `AND len(mac_addr) > 0` to the `WHERE` to keep from catching rows with an empty string `mac_addr`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses - but not having much luck.  
The -- where replace(mac_addr, left(mac_addr, 1), '') = ''; is throwing the following: 
  ORA-00904: "LEFT": invalid identifier
  00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
The -- where replace(mac_addr, '9', '') = ''; - is not returning any results, even though I know there are entries with all 9's.
I did update tag to indicate this is for SQL Developer - not sure if that omission is why these aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

Another Oracle variation:

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
  WHERE TRIM('9' FROM MAC_Addr) IS NOT NULL
```

May need to do more trimming if there could be spaces.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm